# Widgetbook can't access other packages in multi-package Flutter app

Tags: flutter, widgetbook

I'm currently working on a mono repo, multi package Flutter project.

My project is made of 3 packages:

- `myapp`, where most of my code is
- `ui`, where I put my custom themes and widgets that are part of my design system
- `widgetapp`, where I implement a `Widgetbook`, from the [widgetbook](https://pub.dev/packages/widgetbook) package

In my `widgetapp` package, I started with a Widgetbook app as follows:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:widgetbook/widgetbook.dart';
import 'package:widgetbook_annotation/widgetbook_annotation.dart' as widgetbook;

import 'widgetbook.directories.g.dart';

@widgetbook.App()
class WidgetbookApp extends StatelessWidget {

  const WidgetbookApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Widgetbook.material(
      directories: directories,
      addons: [],
      integrations: [],
    );
  }
}
```

Now, in a custom widget, named `CenteredTextButton`, this time located in the `ui` package, I added the following use-case:

```
@widgetbook.UseCase(
  name: "centered text button",
  type: CenteredTextButton,
)

CenteredTextButton primaryCenteredTextButton(BuildContext context) {
  return CenteredTextButton(
      label: "label",
      onTap: () {},
      context: context);
}

class CenteredTextButton extends StatelessWidget {
  ...
}
```

Then, is both `widgetapp` and `ui` packages, I run:

```
dart run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

Also, here are the `widgetapp/pubspec.yaml` dependencies:

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6

  ui:
    path: ../ui

  widgetbook_annotation: ^3.1.0
  widgetbook: ^3.7.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
  widgetbook_generator: ^3.7.0
  build_runner: ^2.4.8
```

But unfortunately, my `CenteredTextButton` use-case doesn't appear in the generated `widgetbook.directories.g.dart` file, therefore it is not visible in the widgetbook.

What did I miss?

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT**: Here is the workaround I found so far:

- I created an empty `WidgetbookApp` in my `ui` package:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:widgetbook/widgetbook.dart';
import 'package:widgetbook_annotation/widgetbook_annotation.dart' as widgetbook;

import 'widgetbook.directories.g.dart';

@widgetbook.App()
class WidgetbookApp extends StatelessWidget {

  const WidgetbookApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Widgetbook.material(directories: directories);

}
```

- now, in my *widgetapp* `WidgetbookApp`, I updated the `directories` parameter as follows:

```
import 'widgetbook.directories.g.dart' as wbdirectories;
import 'package:ui/widgetbook/widgetbook.directories.g.dart' as uidirectories;

@widgetbook.App()
class WidgetbookApp extends StatelessWidget {

  const WidgetbookApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Widgetbook.material(
      directories: [
        ...wbdirectories.directories,
        ...uidirectories.directories,
      ],
      ...
    );
```

I'm not sure if it's the right way to do, so if you have a better solution, I'm interested.